# Need to show pictures from flickr on my site tagged a certain tag

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, flickr

*I'm been going over the available apis and programs out there but what I need is a way to pictures from flickr on my site. Most of the programs I have seen only show pictures that belong to a certain ID. Is there a way to show any picture that is tagged with a certain tag? Like if I need to show pictures tagged Cat on my site how can I do it.

I would be interested in a php based library or if theres something like a jquery plugin that can do it that would be all the  better

Thanks - I'm using the zend framework for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the [**`flickr.photos.search`**](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) method of the API ?

Quoting :

> Return a list of photos matching
>   **some criteria**. 
> Only photos visible to the calling user will be
>   returned. To return private or
>   semi-private photos, the caller must
>   be authenticated with 'read'
>   permissions, and have permission to
>   view the photos. 
> Unauthenticated
>   calls will only return public photos.

And, a bit lower on that page, it seems there is a parameter to filter by tags :

> **`tags`** (Facultatif) 
> A comma-delimited list of tags.
>   
> Photos with one or more of the
>   tags listed will be returned. 
> You
>   can exclude results that match a term
>   by prepending it with a - character.

For example, to search for cats :

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=ee8c6bd0a9d778dba873a3bffed6e503&tags=cat
```

Note : only quickly tried using the [**API Explorer**](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/?method=flickr.photos.search).

Answer (score 0):

you can try [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)

Example query

```
select * from flickr.photos.search where text="lol cat" limit 10
```

[example query](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20%2a%20from%20flickr.photos.search%20where%20text=%22lol%20cat%22%20limit%2010)

it's pretty easy to integrate , YQL gives a REST Query url ,you can use curl and parse the response ( either xml or json ) according to your needs .